# create too much relationship in neo4j take too much

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have a Neo4J database that contain about 90K Node (Which inserted using py2neo and collected from twitter). I want to create relationship between all pair of these nodes and initialize a specific value on the relationship base on Node. I do this with py2neo in python, and try to compare all two nodes and create that relationship, but it takes too much time, for example it takes more than 2 hours to create 80K relationship.

Is there any better way to create this kind of relationships that take less time? Is py2neo slow or it is because of data volume?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to do about 8.1 billion (90K * 90K) operations. If each operation takes 1 millisecond (just for discussion -- this may be way off), then it would take almost 94 days.

So, you want to avoid "cartesian products" with complexity of O(N**2). I would suggest revisiting your use case to see how you can adjust your neo4j data model so that you can avoid having to create so many operations and relationships.

[UPDATE]

If you DO NOT really need to create a relationship between ALL node pairs, but only need need a relationship between specific node pairs, then the comment from @MichaelHunger suggests an approach with approximately `O(N)` complexity.

The approach requires that you first create an index; for example, if your nodes have the label `Foo` and the property of interest for determining whether to create a relationships is `bar`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Foo(bar)
```

Then, you can:

1. `MATCH` all `Foo` nodes.
2. For each matched `Foo` node, use the index to find all other `Foo` nodes that have the appropriate `bar` value (e.g., whose `bar` is double the current `bar`).
3. Create a relationship between the current node and the other node.

   ```
   MATCH (n:Foo)
   MATCH (other:Foo) USING INDEX other:Foo(bar)
   WHERE other.bar = n.bar * 2
   CREATE (n)-[:RELATED_TO]->(m);
   ```

Step 1 has complexity `O(N)`, and the subsequent steps have complexity `O(1)`, resulting in an overall complexity of `O(N)`.

Comment: Yeah you right, it takes too much operation. but how can I create relationship between entities according to their common properties without comparing all of them together :-(

Comment: you can do : `MATCH (n:Label) MATCH (m:Label) USING INDEX m:Label(prop) where m.prop = n.prop create (n)-[:RELATED_TO]->(m)`